# is there an easy way to logout when clicking the back nav item on a navigation controller in swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a login screen that takes an email and password. I'm using firebase Auth.

The login screen is embedded in a navigation controller. From the login screen it goes to a UserDetailsController. There is a "back" nav item in the navbar that comes with the nav controller. I can't actually drag this to be an outlet.

I was wondering if there is an easy way for when the "back" is clicked and the user is returned to the login page to logout the user. The code for logout is relatively simple with firebase Auth. The issue i'm having is working out in LoginController if I returned to here from the UserDetailsController.

I've read up about using self.presentingcontroller to determine which controller i came back from but I keep getting nil. And I wasn't sure if this is the best/only option to determine from which controller I have navigated back from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks pretty straightforward. Hopefully this code will help.

1. In viewDidLoad add a function like this:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

       setupLogOut()

   }
   ```
2. Then set up the function like this with a selector handler method like this:

   ```
   fileprivate func setupLogOut() {

       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogOut))

   }

   @objc func handleLogOut() {

       do {
           try Auth.auth().signOut()

           //  Present the login controller
           let loginController = LoginController()
           let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginController)
           self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

       } catch let signOutErr {
           print("Failed to sign out:", signOutErr)
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: I think in this scenario you can directly add `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` rather than adding the whole Present the login controller logic.

Comment: @Amit interesting, yea I guess you could pop the current controller. I think presenting the login is a bit more explicit (you know exactly where you're going to).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add method to back button. you can also use below method to logout:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  // Your sign out logic here.. 
}
```

Above method get's called when you pop back to login controller.

Comment: Thanks. What I didn't say in my question is that the flow is: Login -> UserDetail -> EmailController and so if I use viewWillDisappear it still gets invoked if going forwards as well as back. But thx!